# Is it OK to log from a Flask Extension?

Tags: flask

I was looking at source from the Flask Extension Registry. I probably looked at about 6 or 7 projects and couldn't find any of them logging output.

My question is: is it OK to do so? If so, should I use app.logger or my own logger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should log - no, you should not use the application logger since the user will not the be able to configure your extension's logging verbosity separately from their own.

Instead, create your own logger using Python's built-in logging module.  Add a `NullHandler` (Python 3 has one, create your own `NullHandler` for Python2) so that by default your library will not log anything.  Add a documentation section explaining how the user can access your logger to setup handlers (and explicitly configure levels, should they so desire).

As is often the case, there is some very good advice on this subject in [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html#library-config):

> #### Configuring Logging for a Library
>
> When developing a library which uses logging, you should take care to document how the library uses logging - for example, the names of loggers used. Some consideration also needs to be given to its logging configuration. If the using application does not use logging, and library code makes logging calls, then (as described in the previous section) events of severity `WARNING` and greater will be printed to `sys.stderr`. This is regarded as the best default behaviour.
>
> If for some reason you *don’t* want these messages printed in the absence of any logging configuration, you can attach a do-nothing handler to the top-level logger for your library. This avoids the message being printed, since a handler will be always be found for the library’s events: it just doesn’t produce any output. If the library user configures logging for application use, presumably that configuration will add some handlers, and if levels are suitably configured then logging calls made in library code will send output to those handlers, as normal.